# SCO OpenServer for consumers?

Tags: sco, openserver

The title says it all; I cannot find a way to purchase SCO OpenServer 6 without being affiliated with a company.

How does one go about purchasing a license key for SCO OpenServer 6 just by themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With server being in the name, it's a server OS and you need to have a business name for it, as well as a website domain.

According to wikipedia, an earlier version was sold under the names "Open Desktop 3.0" and "Open Server 3.0", however OpenServer 6.0 original release is available as Starter and Enterprise, with Enterprise featuring 10 user licenses, 4 Gigabyte of Ram and 4 CPU's, while the Starter is featuring 3 user licenses, 1 Gigabyte of Ram and 1 CPU, being available for only 100 dollars on Ebay, both require a business and your website to be entered at account creation.

Too bad, but it looks like it isn't intended for consumers like you, nor students like me. Please correct me if I'm wrong. You could of course try to contact them to ask if they have a different solution for you.

I hope this information was helpful.